# PHP Datetime Remove Time

Tags: php, time

How do I remove time from a date in PHP, for example:

20170803173418 I want to take 4 minutes and 13 seconds away and get the new datestamp that would be 20170803173005

What code do I use to get this?

*EDIT*

I currently have:

```
$dbTime = $row['aptDeadline'];  // This is the appointment end time stored in DB
$dbTime = new DateTime($dbTime);
$currentTime = date("YmdHis"); // This is the current time
$currentTime = new DateTime($currentTime);
$counterTime = $row['aptDeadline']; //This is the time a countdown clock works from inDB
$counterTime = new DateTime($counterTime);

$difference = $currentTime->diff(new DateTime($dbTime)); // Calculate the time between now and the apt time in the db
```

I now need some code that if the $difference is positive, can take this figure away from the $counterTime stamp

Comment: Provide us with your attempt at solving this problem, we need to see your workings before we can help you toward the solution. Are you putting this date into a database?

Comment: You can put your code into your question by selecting the edit button.

Comment: As simple as `echo (new DateTime('20170803173418'))->sub(new DateInterval('PT4M13S'))->format('YmdHis');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [modify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method of the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class in PHP:

```
<?php

$time = new \DateTime('20170803173418');
$time->modify('-4 minutes')->modify('-13 seconds');

echo $time->format('YmdHis');
```

This will print the result you want.